# javascript - getting the return data of a async function inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am having a problem because chrome api functions are async and I cant get its return value. Consider the following code. *I am using angularjs*

```
    $scope.storageGet = function(param) {
        var returnData; 

        chrome.storage.local.get(param.storageName, function(data) {
            returnData = data;
        });

        return returnData;
    };
```

And when I tried to call it like this:

```
    console.log($scope.storageGet({'storageName': 'users'}));
```

It prints 'undefined' in the console. What I want to see is the obect of users stored in chrome storage. Well, I'm sure that I have data in chrome storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way is to use a promise. In this case it might not matter but if you have a a lot of nested callbacks then a promise is better.

```
$scope.storageGet = function(param) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    chrome.storage.local.get(param.storageName, function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And then you call it like this.

```
$scope.storageGet(param).then(function (data) {

});
```

Comment: ah. Your solution using promise looks good and easy to undestand because its short hahah. I'll try it later.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot return data that is generated by an async function such as `chrome.storage.local.get`, because more likely your function will finish executing before the async function executes. This is why your function returns `undefined`, which is the default value of `returnData`.

A good alternative will be to make your function async as well by using a callback function.

```
$scope.storageGet = function(param, callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(param.storageName, function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
};
```

Now you can call your function this way:

```
$scope.storageGet(param, function(returnData) {
    // do something with returnData
});
```