# get data outside the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, scope

I have a little problem, i would like return a array with function in Angular.
I process my data inside an anonymous function and when I return the array it is empty.

I don't know how to do...

```
getCurrentExchangeTo : function(year, month, country){
            var numberDayPerMonth = [
                31,
                28,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
            ];

            var vm = this;
            this.country = country;

            this.getCurrentExchangeFor = [];
            var hello = "gello"

            for(var i = 0; i < numberDayPerMonth.length; i++){
                if((i + 1) === month){
                    for(let j = 1; j < numberDayPerMonth[i]; j++){
                        $http.get('http://api.fixer.io/' + year + '-0' + month + '-0' + j +'?symbols=' + vm.country).then(function (success) {
                            let countryDay = vm.country
                            vm.getCurrentExchangeFor[j] = success.data.rates[countryDay];
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return vm.getCurrentExchangeFor
        }
```

thanks

EDIT
Using promise but it return only one data

```
getCurrentExchangeTo : function(year, month, country){

            var def = $q.defer();

            var numberDayPerMonth = [
                31,
                28,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
            ];

            var vm = this;
            this.country = country;

            this.getCurrentExchangeFor = [];
            var hello = "gello"

            for(var i = 0; i < numberDayPerMonth.length; i++){
                if((i + 1) === month){
                    for(let j = 1; j < numberDayPerMonth[i]; j++){
                        $http.get('http://api.fixer.io/' + year + '-0' + month + '-0' + j +'?symbols=' + vm.country).then(function (success) {
                            let countryDay = vm.country
                            vm.getCurrentExchangeFor[j] = success.data.rates[countryDay];
                            def.resolve(success.data.rates[countryDay])
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return def.promise
        }
```

Comment: vm.getCurrentExchangeFor is getting populated inside $http.get() which is asynchronous. Before your http call was successfully you are returning the data. Use promise to fix this

Comment: You get empty array because `$http.get` is async thus data is returned before filling up, but .. so may `$http.get()` calls ?,  it will just hit performance badly, Ideally, it should be done at `backend side`.. or use `$q.all()`. and if still want to do it like same, then [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301382/javascript-getting-the-return-data-of-a-async-function-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use promise over here the array that you are returning is empty because array is being returned before it has been populated. 
Since you have a for loop and http call you have use promise.all functionality to make sure all the data has been populated before array is being returned .

Comment: I don't know the promise for the moment. I tested with little tutorial and it working half. The function return only one data.

Comment: that's because it is able to process one data by the time it reaches to return statement

Comment: `getCurrentExchangeService.getCurrentExchangeTo(2015, 2, 'USD').then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });`
I use this for rescup data, but it return an random array length